# Independence in product spaces

Tags: probability

In a math book there is the following theorem, "Let $(\Omega_1,p_1),...,(\Omega_n,p_n)$ be discrete probabilistic spaces and $A_1 \subset \Omega_1,..., A_n\subset \Omega_n$ events in the corresponding spaces. Then, the events $A_1^{n}, A_2^{n},...,A_n^{n}$ are independent in the product space $(\Omega,p)$ of the spaces $(\Omega_1,p_1),(\Omega_2,p_2),...,(\Omega_n,p_n),$ whereby,$$A_i^{n} = \{(\omega_1,..., \omega_n)\in \Omega: \omega_i \in A_i\}."$$ This sounds as if any two random vectors, and thus all random vectors in the product space $(\Omega,p)$ are independent, without regarding if independence occurs in all the $n$ components of the random vectors. Can somebody explain if I am reading incorrectly the theorem that I show here ? Thanks.

Comment: A random vector is just a collection of random variables.  It is not the case that any two random variables are independent. However if $n=3$ and you take random variables of the form \begin{align} X(\omega_1, \omega_2, \omega_3)&=\tilde{X}(\omega_1)\\Y(\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3)&=\tilde{Y}(\omega_2)\\ Z(\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3)&=\tilde{Z}(\omega_3)\end{align} then $\{X,Y,Z\}$ are indeed mutually independent. If we define $W(\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3)=\tilde{W}(\omega_1)$ then of course $W$ may not be independent of $X$, but $W$ is independent of the random vector $(Y,Z)$.